# How can we declare enumerations in QML, without any JavaScript?

Tags: qt, enums, qml

Does QML allow us to define enums? If so, how we can declare enumerations in QML?

I want to declare an enum in QML like the following C++ enum. If possible, I want to do this without any JavaScript.

```
enum Color { RED, GREEN, BLUE };
Color r = RED;
switch(r)
{
    case RED  : std::cout << "red\n";   break;
    case GREEN: std::cout << "green\n"; break;
    case BLUE : std::cout << "blue\n";  break;
}
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use a pure Qml singleton, so you don't need any C++ or javascript.

colors/MyColors.qml:

```
pragma Singleton
import QtQuick 2.5
QtObject {
    id: singleton

    property int red: 0
    property int green: 1
    property int blue: 2
}
```

colors/qmldir:

```
singleton MyColors 1.0 MyColors.qml
```

Your qml file:

```
import "colors" 1.0
// MyColors.red
// MyColors.green
// MyColors.blue
```

Comment: Just a side note, properties cannot begin with an upper case letter.

Comment: At least make your properties in MyColors.qml readonly for this usage.

Answer (score 45):

Since Qt 5.10, enumerations are directly supported in QML. [See Qt documentation which contains sample code.](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#enumeration-attributes)

You can define one with the `enum` keyword. The *type* and its *values* must start with a capital letter but otherwise follow rules for naming a variable (e.g. can include digits and underscore).

To use the enum, you have to explicitly include the full scope including the component `ComponentName.EnumType.EnumValue`. This is true even when using it within the component itself.

e.g.

```
// MyComponent.qml
Rectangle {
    id: root

    // Define Shape enum
    enum Shape {
        None,
        Round,
        Pointy,
        Bobbly,
        Elusive
    }

    // Note: property using enum is of type int
    property int selectedShape: MyComponent.Shape.None

    visible: selectedShape !== MyComponent.Shape.None
    color: selectedShape === MyComponent.Shape.Pointy? "red": "green"
}
```

Note that enumerated values are treated as `int` and you can assign and compare them as such.

Although not documented (and therefore potentially subject to change), by default the first one has value `0`, the second `1`, etc.. However you can assign a non-negative integer value. You can even assign two enum values to the same integer value though that is probably not a good idea. You cannot assign an expression that evaluates to an integer.

e.g.

```
enum Shape {
    None = 5, // valid
    Round, // automatically assigned 6
    Pointy = -1, // not valid
    Bobbly = Round // not valid
    Elusive = (8-7) // not valid
}
```

*Thanks to [Michael Brasser's blog comment about assigning simple values](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2017/12/07/qt-5-10-released/#comment-1201371).*

Comment: where does the 'ComponentName' come from? is that the prefix of QML file name or?

Comment: An example of`ComponentName.EnumType.EnumValue` from my code sample is `MyComponent.Shape.Pointy`. `ComponentName` is the filename of the component you are creating.

Comment: How can this be made to work for the main qml file called by C++, e.g. `main.qml`?

Comment: You create the enum in a component, as above, and then use it in `main.qml` via its full scope, as described above.

Answer (score 10):

First, use `enum class` instead of `enum` for better type safety

```
enum class Color { RED, GREEN, BLUE };
Color r = Color::RED;
```

Then register it for Qt using `Q_ENUMS` (use `Q_ENUM` for Qt 5.5+):

mycolors.h

```
#pragma once

#include <QObject>

class MyColors : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    enum class Color {
        RED,
        GREEN,
        BLUE
    };
    Q_ENUMS(Color)

    static void init();
};
```

To make the enum available in QML, register it (in a mycolors.cpp file):

```
void MyColors::init()
{
    qRegisterMetaType<MyColors::Color>("MyColors::Color");
    qmlRegisterType<MyColors>("MyQmlModule", 1, 0, "MyColors");
}
```

and call `Colors::init()` in your `main()`.

In QML you now have

```
import MyQmlModule 1.0

// MyColors.RED
// MyColors.GREEN
// MyColors.BLUE
```

Answer (score 8):

Since Qt 5.10, you can now also declare Enum types directly in QML: https://v-play.net/updates/v-play-2-15-0-qt-5-10-qt-creator-4-5-support-firebase-data-structures-and-queries#qt-5-10-qml-enum-instanceof

```
// MyText.qml
import QtQuick 2.0

Text {
  enum MyEnum {
    Normal,
    Heading
  }

  property int textType: MyText.MyEnum.Normal

  font.bold: textType == MyText.MyEnum.Heading
  font.pixelSize: textType == MyText.MyEnum.Heading ? 24 : 12
}

// Main.qml
import VPlayApps 1.0

App {
  MyText {
    textType: MyText.MyEnum.Heading
    text: "I'm a headline."
  }
}
```